# counting newlines, spaces, and tabs

Tags: c, whitespace

This problem is from K&R p. 20: Write a program to count blanks, tabs, and newlines.

Here's my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int character, whitespace = 0;

  printf("Enter some text, and press Ctrl-d when you're done.\n\n");

  while((character = getchar() != EOF) {
    if(character == (' ' || '\n' || '\t')) {
      ++whitespace;
    }
  }

  printf("\nYour text contains %d spaces, tabs, and lines.\n", whitespace);

  return 0;
}
```

The program doesn't work. It always gives the answer 0 no matter how many spaces, tabs, and newlines the user text contains. Can anyone see the problem? There's one other strange thing: I have to press Ctrl-d twice for it to register. I have no idea why.
Thanks!

Comment: Your `while` statement is missing a right parenthesis; this is probably a copy and paste error since you say the program compiles and runs.  Make sure that the missing right parenthesis in your program is after `getchar()` and not after `EOF`; otherwise you will get incorrect results.

Comment: You probably have to press `Ctrl-d` twice because you don't hit enter after your input. The shell buffers your input until it sees a linefeed.

Answer (score 18):

```
if(character == (' ' || '\n' || '\t'))
```

tests whether `character` is equal to the result of `(' ' || '\n' || '\t')` (the result of this is 1, indicating that the result of the `||` is true).  You need to test it individually against each of the three possible values, e.g.,

```
if(character == ' ' || character == '\n' || character == '\t')
```

Comment: Expanding - this is a case of an English shorthand that simply doesn't apply in most programming languages. `(a == b) || (a == c)` is not the same as `(a == (b || c))` - the latter is often a bug. Note that the semantics you're intending for `(b || c)` is building a list - in Python you could write IIRC `if a in [b, c, d] :`, but it's still not just a shorthand for the conditional expression you want.

Answer (score 3):

One of the issues you might be hitting is your condition.

Try something like:

```
if (character == '\n' || character == ' ' || character == '\t') {
    ++ whitespace;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parenthesis in your while statement is wrong, it should be

```
while( (character = getchar()) != EOF)
```

You assigned to character the value of the test `getchar() != EOF` which is 1 for whatever character was really read.

Answer (score 1):

the problem with your code is `if(character == (' ' || '\n' || '\t'))` statement. The statement `(' ' || '\n' || '\t')` is equivalent to `32 || 13 || 9` (each character replaced by it equivalent ASCII value) which is equal to `1` as any not zero thing is consider as `true` in C/C++, so effectively you are doing `if(character == 1)`. Now I think you can fix the problem in your code.

Also books says to count blanks, tabs, and newlines separately and you are trying to count the total numbers, so do something like this.

```
if(character == ' ')
  ++blanks;

if(character == '\t')
  ++tabs;

if(character == '\n')
  ++newlines;
```

If you want a complete solution, here is one which i had written a long time back.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int blanks, tabs, newlines;
  int c;


  blanks = 0;
  tabs = 0;
  newlines = 0;

  do {
      c = getchar();
      if(c == ' ') {
          ++blanks;
      }
      else if(c == '\t') {
         ++tabs;
      }
      else if(c == '\n') {
         ++newlines;
      }
  }
  while(c != EOF)

  printf("Blanks: %d\nTabs: %d\nLines: %d\n", blanks, tabs, newlines);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`isspace` will be available as a macro or function depending on your system and saves you having to second guess what might constitute whitespace in your environment. Strictly speaking, it may be all of the following characters on your system. GNU C certainly thinks so.

```
' '
    space
'\f'
    formfeed
'\n'
    newline
'\r'
    carriage return
'\t'
    horizontal tab
'\v'
    vertical tab
```

This is how you can do the test.

```
 #include <ctype.h>

  while((character = getchar() != EOF) {
    if (isspace(character)) whitespace++;
  }
```

Comment: This solves a different problem (it counts extra characters beyond the ones in the problem). -1 for not reading the standard documentation - `isspace` is defined to return true for **exactly** that set of characters, plus potentially others in locales other than the `C` locale (but never fewer).

Comment: While I agree it solves a different problem (a superset of the one asked) I don't see that as injurious to health but rather to be likely of some benefit to an ab initio C programmer - perhaps encouraging some thinking outside the problem posed. How you can conclude that my answer suggests that I didn't read the standard documentation is more curious. In fact, to be able to conclude that **something didn't happen** without evidence quite is intriguing. Perhaps you could elaborate on how you came to such a novel conclusion? -1 for crass argumentation I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The examples above are technically correct. It prints the values only after an `EOF` (End Of File) indicator is called. However, I think there is a better explanation of this exercise (1.8), so let me purpose an alternative. The code below will print the new lines, tabs and blanks right after each new line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define EOL '\n'

/* Excercise 1.8 - K&R's book - 2nd edition. */
main()
{
    int c, newlines, tabs, blanks;

    newlines = 0;
    tabs = 0;
    blanks = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
            ++newlines;
        else if (c == '\t')
            ++tabs;
        else if (c == ' ')
            ++blanks;

        if (c == EOL) {
        printf("Lines: %d\nTabs: %d\nBlanks: %d\n", newlines, tabs, blanks);
        }
    }
}
```