# Counting Tab, Blank and Newlines in C

Tags: c

The code won't work. The counting results of b(blank) and t(tab) are both 0. I think there maybe the issue with my condition set up. Can anyone help?

```
main()
{
int c, b, t, nl;

nl = 0;
b = 0;
t = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        if (c == ' ')
            ++b;
        if (c == '  ')
            ++t;

    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", nl, b, t);

}
```

Comment: Use braces always for loops

Comment: Unlike Python, C doesn't care about indentation. Only the first `if` statement is inside the loop. The other two are after the loop, where `c` is equal to `EOF`.

Comment: Use `'\t'` for `tab` (e.g. `if (c == '\t')` not multiple spaces.

Comment: Had you used *else if* it would have worked!

Comment: Had you stepped through with a debugger, of just added a couple of extra printfs, you would have fixed this without SO;(

Answer (score 2):

The code as posted by you is equivalent to:

```
main()
{
int c, b, t, nl;

nl = 0;
b = 0;
t = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) //your code is equivalent to this
    {
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
    } //the following if conditions fall outside the loop
        if (c == ' ')
            ++b;
        if (c == '\t')//tab is represented by \t not by '  '
            ++t;

    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", nl, b, t);

}
```

You need to add braces around your while loop i.e.

```
int main(void)
{
int c, b, t, nl;

nl = 0;
b = 0;
t = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        if (c == ' ')
            ++b;
        if (c == '\t')
            ++t;
        }
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", nl, b, t);
    return 0;
}
```

Another important thing: `main()` is not standard `C`
[how does int main() and void main() work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928279/how-does-int-main-and-void-main-work)

Answer (score 0):

Two spaces is not char, it is string.
Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221031/counting-newlines-spaces-and-tabs):

```
if(c == ' ')
    b++;
if(c == '\t')
    t++;
if(c == '\n')
    nl++;
```

Comment: `switch` could also be considered?

Comment: for readability concerns yeah but for optimization concerns modern compilers optimizes this kind of 'if' statements too.